# min/max/saddle points of $z=\frac{1}{2} -\sin^2(x^2+y^2)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> $$z=\frac{1}{2} -\sin^2(x^2+y^2)$$ in the interval $0\leq x^2+y^2 \leq \frac{\pi}{6}$

$z_{x}:-2x\sin(2x^2+2y^2)=0$ so $x=0$ or $(2x^2+2y^2)=0$

$z_{y}: -2y\sin(2x^2+2y^2)=0$ so $y=0$ or $(2x^2+2y^2)=0$

$z_{xx}: -2\sin(2x^2+2y^2)-8x^2\cos(2x^2+2y^2)<0$ due to the domain

$z_{yy}: -2\sin(2x^2+2y^2)-8y^2\cos(2x^2+2y^2)<0$ due to the domain

D=$z_{xx}\cdot z_{yy}-[z_{xy}]^2=4\sin(2x^2+2y^2)+16y^2\cos(2x^2+2y^2)\sin(2x^2+2y^2)+16x^2\cos(2x^2+2y^2)\sin(2x^2+2y^2)$

I do not see why $(2x^2+2y^2)=0$ can not be a point and why $D>0$

And why it is maximum

the answers: [1](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimize%201%2F2-sin%5E2(x%5E2%2By%5E2)%20over%200%3C%3Dx%5E2%2By%5E2%3C%3D(pi%2F6)) and [2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximize%201%2F2-sin(x%5E2%2By%5E2)%20over%200%3C%3Dx%5E2%2By%5E2%3C%3D(pi%2F6))

Comment: Who said it isn't?  $2x^2+ 2y^2= 2(x^2+ y^2)= 0$ is equivalent to $x^2+ y^2= 0$.  Since a square is never negative, The only way $x^2+ y^2$ can equal 0 is if x= y= 0.  That is your (0, 0) point.

Comment: but $D$ can still be $D=0$

Comment: $\sin^2(x)$ is and increasing function in the interval $0 \le x \le \frac{\pi}{6}$, so the maximum value of $-\sin^2(x)$ is at origin. also $x^2+y^2=0$ has the only solution $x=y=0$. you can also solve this problem with $r^2=x^2+y^2$ to see why is this happening( in other words in polar coordinates).

Comment: It is obvious by inspection that $z$ has a local maximum at $(0,0)$. On the other hand all second partials are $=0$ at $(0,0)$, so that the second derivative test is inconclusive.

Comment: funny for [tan](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Maximize[{1%2F2-Tan[x^2%2By^2],+0%3C%3Dx^2%2By^2%3C%3D1},+{x,+y}]) and [erf](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Maximize[{1%2F2-Erf[x^2%2By^2],+0%3C%3Dx^2%2By^2%3C%3D1},+{x,+y}])

Answer (score 0):

I really do not know why Wolfram Alpha gives you result which states that there are four local maxima because it seems to me that I can elementarily prove that there is only one local maximum, if someone finds a flaw in my stream of thought let me know about it.

First, it is clear that $(0,0)$ is a local maximum.

Suppose now that there exists some local maximum $(x_0,y_0) \neq (0,0)$. That would mean that there exists some $\epsilon_0$ such that we have $z(x_0,y_0) \geq z(x,y)$ for every $(x,y)$ inside the ball of radius $\epsilon_0$ that has the center at the point $(x_0,y_0)$.

So it means that we would have $\frac{1}{2} -\sin^2(x_0^2+y_0^2) \geq \frac{1}{2} -\sin^2(x^2+y^2)$ for every $(x,y)$ in the ball with center at the point $(x_0,y_0)$ with radius $\epsilon_0$.

So we would have $\sin^2(x_0^2+y_0^2) \leq \sin^2(x^2+y^2)$ for all $(x,y)$ inside that ball.

Now choose some point $(x_1,y_1)$ that lies in the ball which is such that we have $x_1^2 + y_1^2 < x_0^2 + y_0^2$ (it is clearly obvious that such a point exists). This implies that $\sin(x_1^2+y_1^2) < \sin(x_0^2+y_0^2)$ which implies $\sin^2(x_1^2+y_1^2) < \sin^2(x_0^2+y_0^2)$, so we have arrived at the contradiction and the only maximum is $(0,0)$.

If it is not clear to you that $(0,0)$ is a local maximum observe that for every pair $(x,y)$ which satisfies $0 < x^2+y^2 \leq \frac{\pi}{6}$ We have $0 < \sin^2(x^2+y^2) \leq \frac {1}{4}$ and for $(0,0)$ we have $\sin^2(0^2+0^2)=0$.